# Is jQuery 1.x vulnerable to "non-explicit data type cross-site scripting"?

Tags: jquery

We recently received the following email from https://nospam_srcclr.com (remove nospam_ for the real URL).

> Thank you for your prompt reply. We have identified [our project] as being vulnerable to a cross-site scripting vulnerability through JQuery.
>
> https://nospam_srcclr.com/security/cross-site-scripting-xss-through-execution-non-explicit-data-type/javascript/sid-2250/fix
>
> A copy of the JQuery version 1.11.3 is included in the project here.  JQuery is vulnerable to cross-site scripting through execution of non-explicit data type. The vulnerable section of code used in [our project] is seen here.
>
> To mitigate this issue, we recommend upgrading JQuery to 3.0.0.

Is jQuery 1.x actually unsafe to use?

Comment: It's worth noting the top five links for 'XSS Non-Explicit Data Type' are all for their website.

Comment: Thanks you both. Please create your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you not fetch any javascript from another `untrusted` domain by ajax, it still safe.

If you did,
you can manually apply this simple patch to your current jquery:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/b078a62013782c7424a4a61a240c23c4c0b42614

Comment: This is the real answer to the question. This is the vulnerability referred to in the link, the other vulnerably is old news.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery version 1.11.3 is fine to use, the cross-site scripting vulnerability was fixed in [**1.6.3**](https://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/01/jquery-1-6-3-released/). Versions before 1.6.3 are vulnerable to it. Upgrading to jQuery 3.0.0 isn't necessary, especially if you plan on supporting older browsers such as IE 8.

Comment: Actually it was fixed in 1.12, but then reverted and in 1.12.4. So jQuery 1.12.3 is safe but there might be compatibility issues. See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3011